# Remove at index function removes all elements before index

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I use this remove method to remove the 3rd element of list. But it removes all the elements before the specified index. So if Jhon, Sam, Philip, Emma are the list elements, if I remove 3rd element, the only remaining element is Nick. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.*;

class List {
    Customer listPtr;
    int index;

    public void add(Customer customer) {
        Customer temp = customer;
        if (listPtr == null) {
            listPtr = temp;
            index++;
        } else {
            Customer x = listPtr;
            while (x.next != null) {
                x = x.next;
            }
            x.next = temp;
            index++;
        }
    }

    public void remove(int index) {
        int size = size();
        Customer tmp = listPtr, tmp2;
        int i = 0;
        while (i != size) {
            if ((i + 1) == index) {
                tmp2 = tmp;
                listPtr = tmp2.next;
                break;
            }
            tmp = tmp.next;
            ++i;
        }
    }

    public int size() {
        int size = 0;
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            temp = temp.next;
            size++;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public void printList() {
        Customer temp = listPtr;
        while (temp != null) {
            System.out.println(temp);
            temp = temp.next;
        }
    }
}

class DemoList {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List list = new List();
        Customer c1 = new Customer("10011", "Jhon");
        Customer c2 = new Customer("10012", "Sam");
        Customer c3 = new Customer("10013", "Philip");
        Customer c4 = new Customer("10014", "Emma");        
        list.add(c1);
        list.add(c2);
        list.add(c3);
        list.add(c4);
        list.remove(3);
        System.out.println(list.size());
        list.printList();
    }
}

class Customer {
    String id;
    String name;
    Customer next;

    public Customer(String id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return id + " : " + name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object ob) {
        Customer c = (Customer) ob;
        return this.id.equals(c.id);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should consider keeping track of size and not calculate it every time. It's an O(n) operation and hence every method of your list is O(n) now. That index you increment on add() should be size instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void remove(int index) {
  if (i == 0) {
      // TODO: do some checks (listPtr is set, has next...)
      listPtr = listPtr.next;
  }
  else {
      int currentIndex = 0;
      Customer currentElement = listPtr;
      while (currentIndex != size()) {
          if ((currentIndex + 1) == index) {
              currentElement.next = currentElement.next.next;
              break;
          }
          currentElement = currentElement.next;
          currentIndex++;
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with the `remove()` method.

First of all, you should only be changing `listPtr` if `index == 0`.

In all other cases, you need to adjust `node.next` of the node at position `index - 1`.

P.S. Having `index` as a data member of `List` looks like an accident waiting to happen.